# UITabBar top of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uitabbarcontroller

I need to put my tab bar at the top of the screen.

I've tried and I did, this is the code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        self.tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
  }
```

the problem is I when I turn the screen of my device.

I should regenerate the layout and change in this way:

```
self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

How can I change this every time you turn the screen?

**EDIT:**

New Code:

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  {
        //check tabBar not null
        if (self.tabBar != nil)
        {
            //make changes in frame here according to orientation if any
            self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 00, y: 20, width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 49)
        }
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() 
  {
     //Make changes in frame according to your requirement
    self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.bounds.size.width,49);
    //resizing here
    self.tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `UITabBar` in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    //Make changes in frame according to your requirement
    self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.bounds.size.width,49);
    //resizing here
    self.tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;
}
```

Add below method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    //check tabBar not null
    if (self.tabBar != nil)
    {
        //make changes in frame here according to orientation if any
        self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 00, y: 20, width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 49)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to write the function returns me this error: "UITabBar is not a subtype of NSString"

Comment: I have made some changes ie added only self for tabBar. It shows this error in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: I edited the question with the new code, but it gives me the same error

Comment: The problem is from your side then as your checking some object is null or not like this ie if(anyObject) which is in objective-c and not in swift . Check like this if(anyObject != nil) which is in swift

Comment: mmm I find nothing about.. However, the reply I was of help. Thank You